# How do I check if an array contains values from another array?

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays, each of them `var_dump()`'ed below.

I've tried with `array_intersect()`, but nothing is returned, and no errors:

```
if (array_intersect($userInterests, $interests)) {
   echo "found";
}
```

Small array, $userInterests:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (1) {
    ["interestId"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
    ["interestId"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (1) {
    ["interestId"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

Large array, $interests:

```
array(15) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["interestName"]=>
    string(5) "Musik"
    ["interestID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#11 (2) {
    ["interestName"]=>
    string(3) "Mad"
    ["interestID"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#12 (2) {
    ["interestName"]=>
    string(6) "Rejser"
    ["interestID"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#13 (2) {
    ["interestName"]=>
    string(10) "Mad Moneyz"
    ["interestID"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#14 (2) {
    ["interestName"]=>
    string(5) "Biler"
    ["interestID"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [5]=>
  object(stdClass)#15 (2) {
    ["interestName"]=>
    string(7) "Netflix"
    ["interestID"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [6]=>
  object(stdClass)#16 (2) {
    ["interestName"]=>
    string(26) "Lange gåture på stranden"
    ["interestID"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  [7]=>
  object(stdClass)#17 (2) {
    ["interestName"]=>
    string(15) "Bjergbestigning"
    ["interestID"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
```

My goal is to mark select options as selected, like this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $interest->interestID; ?>"<?php echo (in_array($interest->interestID, $userInterests)) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $interest->interestName; ?></option>
```

$interest is the specific interest taken out from the bigger array, $interests

$userInterests is the smaller array

Comment: You should restructure your question to stress the fact that you actually want help marking the correct option as collected. Finding common values is another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your first array is actual an array of objects. And you are basically asking your PHP does this array of objects contain `3`? This obviously is not a valid question. You need to convert the array of objects to a group of numbers.

From

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#8 (1) {
      ["interestId"]=>
        string(1) "2"
    }
  [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
      ["interestId"]=>
        string(1) "3"
    }
  [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#9 (1) {
      ["interestId"]=>
        string(1) "5"
    }
}
```

To

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
  [2]=>
    string(1) "5"
}
```

First of all, convert your user's interests to a simple array.

```
$userInterestsSimple = array();
foreach ($userInterests as $userInterest)
    $userInterestsSimple[] = $userInterest->interestId;
```

Afterwards, your check with `in_array()` will work properly:

```
<option value="<?php echo $interest->interestID; ?>"
  <?php
    echo (in_array($interest->interestID, $userInterestsSimple)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
  ?>
>
    <?php echo $interest->interestName; ?>
</option>
```

Comment: @VirtusBB added a brief explanation of what was going on and how it was fixed to help you in future issues.

Answer (score 0):

Merge them with [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and compare the number of elements [sizeof()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sizeof.php)

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$array2 = array(6,7,8,9,10);

if(sizeof(array_merge($array1, $array2)) < sizeof($array1) + sizeof($array2))
    //Common values
```

To check if an element is in the array use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php)

Comment: No, you wanted to check if the arrays have common elements. You merge them and compare the size of the merged array with the sum of the sizes. If the merged array has LESS elements, there were common elements!